# Sequelize how to transform objects list

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code

```
employees = []

async function fillEmployeesList() {
    await Employe.findAll().then(allEmployes => {
        employees = allEmployes;
        console.log('All employees: ' + allEmployes[0].nom);
    });
}
```

And I want to transform the raw object to correct employee object, how can I do this? Because allEmployes  is currently a list of sequelize object, I want it to be a list of Employee object, how? (Sorry english is not my first language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
employees = []
 async function fillEmployeesList() {
    const allEmployees = await Employe.findAll();
    employees = allEmployees.map(employee => {
    return employee.toJSON();
 });
}
```

im adding just this return employee.toJSON(); line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to assign employees data directly to a variable without using callback and manipulate those data as per your requirements you can do like this.

```
employees = []

async function fillEmployeesList() {
    const allEmployees = await Employe.findAll();
    employees = allEmployees.map(employee => {
        return {"nom", employee.nom, "other_key": employee.name};
    })
    console.log(employees);//will print employees modified data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
employees = []

async function fillEmployeesList() {
await Employe.findAll({raw: true}).then(allEmployes => {
    employees = allEmployes;
    console.log('All employees: ' + allEmployes[0].nom);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the raw data and don't want to update anything, you can do like this to get the raw data.

```
employees = []

async function fillEmployeesList() {
await Employe.findAll({raw: true}).then(allEmployes => {
    employees = allEmployes;
    console.log('All employees: ' + allEmployes[0].nom);
});
}
```

You can read about it here. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#raw-queries